# Get RethinkDB query working in Ruby on Rails

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-ruby, nobrainer

I have a ReQL query...

```
r.db('development').table('responses').filter({
  survey_id: 9
}).concatMap(r.row.getField('numerical_answers')).filter({
  type: 'CustomerEffortAnswer'
}).sum('number')
```

...that I would like to get working in [NoBrainer](https://nobrainer.io) because I can't seem to get it working on Ruby on Rails. When I try to run just the ReQL in Rails like so...

```
NoBrainer.run do |r|
  return_count = r.db('development').table('responses').filter({ survey_id: id }).concatMap(r.row.getField('numerical_answers')).filter({type: 'CustomerEffortAnswer'}).sum('number')
end
```

...I get the error:

```
Sorry, r.row is not available in the ruby driver. Use blocks instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to convert the code over to Ruby language:

```
return_count = NoBrainer.run do |r|
  r.db('development').table('responses')
  .filter({:survey_id => 9})
  .concat_map { |doc| doc[:numerical_answers] }
  .filter({:type => 'CustomerEffortAnswer'})
  .sum('number')
end
```